# Proofing an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume we have three points $ a , b , c $ where $a < b < c$ and $b-a=c-b=h $

How can I proof for every $x \in [a,b]$ we have $|(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)| \leq \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}h^{3}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3001624/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Can you do the case $(a,b,c)=(-1,0,1)$?

Comment: I tried to break problem for $a<x<b$ and $b<x<c$ but the only thing I get its $|(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)| \leq 2h^{3}$

Comment: Have you tried elementary calculus to find max of $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$?  Note that for $a\le x\le b$, the expression is always non-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=|(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)|=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=(x-a)(b-x)(c-x)\tag{1}$$

Introduce substitution:

$$b-x=u, \quad u\in[0,h]\tag{2}$$

$$x-a=(b-a)-(b-x)=h-u\tag{3}$$

$$c-x=(c-b)+(b-x)=h+u\tag{4}$$

Now replace (2,3,4) into (1):

$$f(u)=(h-u)u(h+u)=u(h^2-u^2)=uh^2-u^3\tag{5}$$

$$f'(u)=h^2-3u^2=0\implies u=\frac{h\sqrt{3}}{3}\tag{6}$$

$$f(u)|_{u=\frac{h\sqrt{3}}{3}}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}h^{3}\tag{7}$$

Obviously $f''(u)=-3u^2<0$ for all values of $u\ne0$. This proves that (7) is indeed the maximum value.